# How to generate random street from city's IP?

Tags: google-maps, ip, detection

Is there any way I could generate random street if I detect city from an IP. Let say I live in London and my app detects it right and returns a value for a city which is in our case London. Is there any way I could generate some fake street address which is located somwehre in London with GPS coordinates? For example let say Google Maps generates me random street in London for city center radius of 10km.

Answer (score 0):

To get coordinates you can use the following service (replace the address parameter with the name of the city):

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=london&sensor=false

The first result will give you the location:

```
"location" : {
           "lat" : 51.5073509,
           "lng" : -0.1277583
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use Google's [reverse geocoding api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse). If you pass it gps coordinates, it will return an address.

If you want to guarantee that you find a location, use the [Place Search](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). 
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?key=<apikey>&location=<lat>,<lng>&radius=<radiustosearch>`